# Como colocar el valor de una consulta en un textarea?

Tags: mysql, json, ckeditor, textarea

un saludo a todos, tengo un formulario en una ventana modal con varios inputs y un textarea, toda la información se guarde en una base de datos sin ningún problema, incluyendo la información del textarea, que a propósito utiliza el ckeditor para ingresar la información. Cuando realizo la consulta para editar la información obtenida todos los campos reciben la información correspondiente según fue ingresada, menos el textarea el cual se queda en blanco. como paso el contenido de la variable 'message_body' al textarea

```js
function EditPublic(id){
$.post("/vistas/recursos/recurso_fileinput.php?op=mostrar",{id : id}, function(data, status)
   { 
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                $("#ModalPublicarAnuncio").modal("show");
                $("#TipoUsiario").val(data.usuario);
                $("#TipoUsiario").attr('disabled', true);
                $('#NameUser').val(data.nombre);
             $("#NameUser").attr('disabled', true);
             $('#txt_title').val(data.message_title);
                $("#txt_title").attr('disabled', true);
                $('#txt_announcement').val(data.message_body);
 $('.modal-title').text("Editar mensaje");
 $('#id').val(id);
 $('#action').val("Edit");
     
      });
        }
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <textarea  class="form-control" id="txt_announcement" name="txt_announcement" value="txt_announcement" placeholder="Escriba el contenido" require></textarea>
</div>

$datos = $publicacion->get_publicacion_por_id($_POST["id"]);

        
            foreach($datos as $row){

                    $output["id"] = $row["id"]; 
                    $output["message_title"] = $row["message_title"];
                    $output["message_body"] = $row["message_body"];
                    $output["usuario"] = $row["usuario"];
                    $output["nombre"] = $row["nombre"];
            }
        echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: ¿Puedes hacer un console.log(data) después de parsearlo y mostrar qué resultado obtienes en la consola? La asignación de datos al textarea en principio parace correcta.

Comment: la consulta funciona, haciendo pruebas apunto la variable que contiene la información del textarea a un input y sale sin problema, pero no logro que aparezca en el textarea

Comment: ¿Si pruebas $('#txt_announcement').val("probando textarea"); escribe? Si la respuesta es si (yo lo he probado con tu código y funciona) el problema está en el contenido de la variable, si la respuesta es no, el problema está en otra parte del código que afecta al textarea, por eso puse lo de hacer console.log

Comment: por console.log(data) muestra toda la consulta correcta incluyendo el contenido del textarea, pero en el campo sigue sin emprimir el contenido.

Comment: Por console.log(data) muestra toda la consulta completa, incluyendo el contenido del textarea, pero en el campo sigue sin imprimir el contenido.  no creo que sea problema de contenido por que haciendo la prueba con los datos de un input debería realizar la impresión. tampoco lo hace

Comment: de echo hice la prueba enviando la data con una $_SESSION y si la imprime, pero así muestra los datos del elemento sobre el cual hice clic previamente y no el actual.         $datos = $publicacion->get_publicacion_por_id($_POST["id"]);
        for($i=0; $i<sizeof($datos);$i++){
         $_SESSION['IdArticulo']=  $datos[$i]["message_body"] ; 
        }

Comment: pues parece que el problema está en otra parte del código que afecta al textarea y no es reproducible, quizás tengas asociado algún tipo de editor al textarea. Pongo un ejemplo de funcionamiento de tu código para que veas que no es el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Esto es un ejemplo de funcionamiento correcto, en el primer textarea se rellena con un texto, en el segundo con una variable creada por php que sigue el proceso lógico presentado en la pregunta.

```
PHP

$output["message_body"] = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. ";

$data = json_encode($output);

echo $data;

//resultado {"message_body":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. "}
```

```js
var message = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.";
$('#txt_announcement1').val(message);

var data_get = '{"message_body":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. "}';
var data = JSON.parse(data_get);
$('#txt_announcement2').val(data.message_body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <textarea  class="form-control" id="txt_announcement1" name="txt_announcement1" value="txt_announcement" placeholder="Escriba el contenido" require></textarea>
  <textarea  class="form-control" id="txt_announcement2" name="txt_announcement2" value="txt_announcement" placeholder="Escriba el contenido" require></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: En principio pensaba que el problema seria el ckeditor, pero veo que si paso la consulta  por una variable $_SESSION si realiza la impresión, el problema de hacerlo así es que me retorna la penúltima consulta, cuando se da clic en editar abre el formulario sin ningún dato, cierro el formulario, presiono de nuevo  y ahí si carga la consulta. si cierro el formulario y paso a realizar la edición de otro artículo carga la consulta anterior